# whisker-box plot through a folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a directory with 7 sub-folders within. I wanted to plot a whisker-box plot for all folders together. Through the "for" loop, I can see the contents of my folders but when I want to do, it does not recognize files. My code is below:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import rcParams
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
%matplotlib qt


root = r'/home/hossein/Desktop/Out/INTERSECTION/BETA 15'
xx=[]
percentage=[]
my_list = os.listdir(root)
my_list =  [file for file in my_list if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, file))]
for directory in my_list:
    CASES = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, directory)) if file.startswith('config')]
    files = {}    
    if len(CASES)==0:
        continue
    CASES.sort()


    for filename in CASES:

        with open(fos.path.join(root, directory,filename), "r") as file:

            if file in files:
                continue
        #files[filename] = file.read()
            lines = file.readlines()
            x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
            y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

            y_new = np.array(y)

            g = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),100)

            h = min(y)*0.9
            t = max(y)*0.9


            xx = []

            for i in range(1,len(x)):

                if (y[i] < h or y[i] > t):
                    xx.append(x[i])

            percent = len(xx)/len(y)

            percentage.append(percent)


    green_diamond = dict(markerfacecolor='g', marker='D')


    plt.boxplot(percentage,flierprops=green_diamond,whis=0.001,label=directory)
```

The error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'configuration_1001.out'
```

Comment: Try printing `os.path.join(root, directory,filename)` to see if it is what you expect?

Comment: @DavidG I could plot one by one but when I want to plot them together I faced overlaying plots.